# Convert R dataframe columns containing lists into data frame columns

Tags: json, r, nested, dataframe

I have a nasty nested JSON file, from which I'd like to extract a particular part of the data into a data frame.  I've been able to get the data I'm interested in into a data frame, but the first column contains a nested list.

```
       PlayerStats.PlayerStat                               X.attributes.id X.attributes.player_name X.attributes.position X.attributes.position_id
1  list('@value'=c("","","",...), '@attribute'=c("","","",...)) 8683                 John Smith                Back 7                       15
2  list('@value'=c("","","",...), '@attribute'=c("","","",...)) 19104              Tony Fratone                Back 6                       14
3  list('@value'=c("","","",...), '@attribute'=c("","","",...)) 10091              Ryan Elliott                Back 5                       13
```

Ideally, I would like to convert the '@attribute' list into data frame columns. First, I'm not sure how to access each list to perform an operation on them.  Additionally, the "@" seems to be throwing a wrench into the works as well.

I've tried this:

```
matchData <- fromJSON("json_data.json", flatten = TRUE)

# Get player stats for team 1
team1 <- data.frame(matchData$TeamDetail$Team$Player[1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pStats <- (team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat)

stats <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, pStats))
```

But it ends up creating a new row for each column value.

I'm banging my head against the wall (maybe because of lack of sleep) - any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the JSON, which represents the stats for one player:

```
"Team": [{
                "Player": [{
                    "PlayerStats": {
                        "PlayerStat": [{
                            "@value": "",
                            "@attributes": {
                                "restart_opp_player": "0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@value": "",
                            "@attributes": {
                                "kick_oppn_collection": "0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@value": "",
                            "@attributes": {
                                "kicks_from_hand": "4"
                            }

                        ...

                    ]
                },
                "@attributes": {
                    "id": "7654",
                    "player_name": "Tom Smith",
                    "position": "Back 7",
                    "position_id": "15"
                }
            },
```

And here's part of the output of `dput(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat)` (sorry for the large chunk of data):

```
    `@attributes.kick_charged_down` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `@attributes.lineout_throw_won_penalty` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
...
, `@attributes.runs` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "5", NA, NA), `@attributes.goals` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "0", NA), `@attributes.penalty_conceded_high_tackle` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0")), .Names = c("@value", "@attributes.restart_opp_player", 
"@attributes.kick_oppn_collection", "@attributes.kicks_from_hand", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_killing_ruck", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_own_half", 
"@attributes.kick_penalty_good", "@attributes.lineouts_won", 
"@attributes.kick_in_field", "@attributes.rucks_won", "@attributes.minutes_played_second_half", 
"@attributes.metres", "@attributes.scrums_lost_reversed", "@attributes.tries", 
"@attributes.lineout_won_opp_throw", "@attributes.lineouts_infringe_opp", 
"@attributes.scrums_won_penalty_try", "@attributes.turnover_turnover_forward_pass", 
"@attributes.scrums_won_free_kick", "@attributes.scrums_won_pushover_try", 
"@attributes.lineouts_lost", "@attributes.turnover_own_half", 
"@attributes.dropped_catch", "@attributes.missed_tackles", "@attributes.scrums_lost_outright", 
"@attributes.collection_loose_ball", "@attributes.restart_error_not_ten", 
"@attributes.scrums_lost_penalty", "@attributes.missed_conversion_goals", 
"@attributes.pc_kick_percent", "@attributes.kicks", "@attributes.restarts_lost", 
"@attributes.pen_defs", "@attributes.missed_goals", "@attributes.lineout_won_steal", 
"@attributes.minutes_played_before_second_half_extra", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_foul_play", 
"@attributes.penalty_goals", "@attributes.lineout_throw_lost_handling_error", 
"@attributes.kick_penalty_bad", "@attributes.kick_percent_success", 
"@attributes.lineout_throw_won_clean", "@attributes.restart_opp_error", 
"@attributes.drop_goals_converted", "@attributes.conversion_goals", 
"@attributes.points", "@attributes.mauls_won_outright", "@attributes.clean_breaks", 
"@attributes.collection_failed", "@attributes.kick_in_touch", 
"@attributes.handling_error", "@attributes.carries_support", 
"@attributes.kick_possession_retained", "@attributes.scrums_lost_free_kick", 
"@attributes.id", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_dissent", "@attributes.try_assist", 
"@attributes.defenders_beaten", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_lineout_offence", 
"@attributes.catch_from_kick", "@attributes.scrums_won_penalty", 
"@attributes.minutes_played_first_half_extra", "@attributes.collection_from_kick", 
"@attributes.restart_own_player", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_line_out_offence", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_collapsing_maul", "@attributes.lineout_success", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_offside", "@attributes.collection_success", 
"@attributes.turnover_carried_in_touch", "@attributes.player_id", 
"@attributes.restarts_success", "@attributes.rucks_lost", "@attributes.turnover_bad_pass", 
"@attributes.mauls_won_try", "@attributes.ball_out_of_play", 
"@attributes.lineout_non_straight", "@attributes.turnover_carried_over", 
"@attributes.lineout_throw_won_tap", "@attributes.scrums_won_outright", 
"@attributes.turnover_lost_in_ruck_or_maul", "@attributes.tackle_success", 
"@attributes.kick_out_of_play", "@attributes.kick_possession_lost", 
"@attributes.carries_not_made_gain_line", "@attributes.missed_penalty_goals", 
"@attributes.yellow_cards", "@attributes.offload", "@attributes.retained_kicks", 
"@attributes.passes", "@attributes.carries_crossed_gain_line", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_delib_knock_on", "@attributes.lineouts_to_own_player", 
"@attributes.team_id", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_opp_half", 
"@attributes.restart_halfway", "@attributes.lineout_throw_lost_free_kick", 
"@attributes.minutes_played_before_penalty_shootOut", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_other", 
"@attributes.mauls_won", "@attributes.turnover_forward_pass", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_scrum_offence", "@attributes.tackles", 
"@attributes.pen_offs", "@attributes.lineout_throw_lost_not_straight", 
"@attributes.try_kicks", "@attributes.mauls_lost_turnover", "@attributes.penalties_conceded", 
"@attributes.mauls_won_penalty", "@attributes.lineout_won_own_throw", 
"@attributes.mauls_won_penalty_try", "@attributes.minutes_played_before_second_half", 
"@attributes.lineout_throw_lost_outright", "@attributes.restart_22m", 
"@attributes.mauls_lost_outright", "@attributes.mauls_lost", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_collapsing_offence", "@attributes.minutes_played_first_half", 
"@attributes.turnover_opp_half", "@attributes.turnover_knock_on", 
"@attributes.minutes_played_before_first_half_extra", "@attributes.game_id", 
"@attributes.turnover_won", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_obstruction", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_stamping", "@attributes.restart_error_out_of_play", 
"@attributes.kick_metres", "@attributes.collection_interception", 
"@attributes.pickup", "@attributes.minutes_played_second_half_extra", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_handling_in_ruck", "@attributes.try_assists", 
"@attributes.minutes_played_total", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_early_tackle", 
"@attributes.lineout_throw_lost_penalty", "@attributes.minutes_played_before_first_half", 
"@attributes.carries_metres", "@attributes.true_retained_kicks", 
"@attributes.bad_passes", "@attributes.kick_try_scored", "@attributes.turnovers_conceded", 
"@attributes.red_cards", "@attributes.kick_touch_in_goal", "@attributes.kick_charged_down", 
"@attributes.lineout_throw_won_penalty", "@attributes.penalty_conceded_wrong_side", 
"@attributes.total_lineouts", "@attributes.gain_line", "@attributes.lineout_throw_won_free_kick", 
"@attributes.restarts_won", "@attributes.runs", "@attributes.goals", 
"@attributes.penalty_conceded_high_tackle"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
152L)))
```

Comment: Could you share a snippet of your JSON file? Otherwise we're all guessing on what you're doing.

Comment: Could you add the result of dput(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat) or dput(head(team1))?

Comment: I've added a snippet of the JSON file, as well as a snippet from 'dput'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will convert the Playerstats of the first row into a data frame:

```
pStats <- data.frame(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat[1])
```

The following code will go through all the rows in PlayerStats and combines all the results using the foreach package

```
require(foreach)

pStats<-  foreach(i=1:dim(team1)[1], .combine=rbind) %do% {
    pStats <- data.frame(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat[i])
    }
```

#

On how to handle and @:

```
example <- list('@value'=c("A","B","C"), '@attribute'=c("1","2","3"))
```

With `example$'@value'` and `example$'@attribute'` you can access the data by using the labels

Ad the folowwing code will generate and data.frame `df.example <- data.frame(example)`

Comment: Thanks @Berecht - this seems to produce the same output as before - one value on each row, resulting in 3496 rows, instead of 23.

Comment: By changing the foreach .combine statement cbind you can join by column . Note that the lengths of the combined data.frame has the same length.

Comment: @user256599 - By changing the foreach .combine statement cbind you can join by column . Note that the lengths of the combined data.frame has the same length. The following priciple: `stats <- cbind(data.frame(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat[1]),data.frame(team1$PlayerStats.PlayerStat[2]))`

Comment: I obtained the same results using 'cbind', but your suggestions led me to the realization that the issue is in the lists themselves.  If I look at one of the JSON elements, such as this:

Comment: I obtained the same results using 'cbind', but your suggestions led me to realize that the issue is in the lists themselves. If I look at one of the JSON elements, such as this:

'{
                            "@value": "",
                            "@attributes": {
                                "kicks_from_hand": "4"
                            }'

the list contains something like ' "@attributes.penalty_conceded_high_tackle" = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, .... NA, "4") '

It seems like there should only be the one value of "4". I think that it's the way the JSON file is imported?

Comment: If something is nested R will handle it by putting it in a list. In your snippet from the JSON code i see that you got a lot of nested documents, and also nested documents inside nested documents. You can definitely get your desired data frame, by play with unlist(), data.frame(), cbind() and rbind(). How does your desired data.frame looks like? (e.g: collumns: attribute, value, id. player, position... )

Comment: Yes, it is a very nasty nested JSON file. Ideally, I would like to expand the "attributes" list into individual columns, and add them to the existing columns. Something like: 

"X.attributes.id"          
"X.attributes.player_name" 
"X.attributes.position"   
"X.attributes.position_id"
"X.attributes.restart_opp_player"                     
"X.attributes.kick_oppn_collection"                   
"X.attributes.kicks_from_hand"                        
"X.attributes.penalty_conceded_killing_ruck"          
"X.attributes.penalty_conceded_own_half"
... 
etc.